# probabity a box contain 10 balls 4 balls are red and 6 balls are white 2 balls are drawn with replacement

Tags: probability

by logic why the probability of pick 1 ball red is greater than take 2 red ... by logic if a pick a ball from box and return it back the probaility to take the same color is equal the first drawn by example the p(r)is 0.48 while the p(2r) is 0.16

Comment: If one draws a ball then puts is back then draws again then the probability of the event that the second one is red is the same as that of the first was red. (Just like you explained.) So what is the question?

Comment: why the probability decrease but by logic if i draws one ball then put it back the probability must be the same???? thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing I think is the meaning of picking one red. Picking 1 red means either the first one is red or the second one is red but not both of them.

Hence the probability to pick one red is $p(r).p(w)+p(w).p(r)$ the probability that you pick the first red and the second white plus the probability that the first is white and the second is red (the probability multiplies here because the 2 events are independent).

On the other hand probability to pick 2 reds is $p(r).p(r)$.

I hope it's clear.

**Edit:**

The probability that you have 7 head in a row is low and not 1/2 because what you are asking is that all the 6th first toss are head **and** the last one is head as well.

1/2 is the probability that the last toss is head but it doesn't say anything on the first toss.

If you are given that 6th the first toss are head then the probability to have a head on the 7th toss is 1/2. This is expressed by the following conditional probability: $P(X_7=h\mid X_1=h,...,X_6=h)=1/2$

But if you are asking the probability that all the 7 toss are head, you don't know that the first 6 are necessarily head, so you have to take into account the probability that this happens.

Is it clearer?

An other way to see it (for 2 toss) is that all the possible outcomes of two toss are:
$(h,h),(t,h),(t,t),(h,t)$ the probability that the second toss is head is $$\frac{|\{(h,h),(t,h)\}|}{|\{(h,h),(t,h),(t,t),(h,t)\}|}=2/4=1/2$$ whereas the probability that the two toss are head is $$\frac{|\{(h,h)\}|}{|\{(h,h),(t,h),(t,t),(h,t)\}|}=1/4$$

For your ball it's the same. If you gives them all a number between 1 and 10 such that the first 4 balls are red the set of possible picking is: $\{(i,j)\mid i,j\in\{1..10\}\}$.
Hence the probability that the second one is red is:

$$\frac{|\{(i,j)\mid i\in\{1..10\},j\in\{1..4\}\}|}{|\{(i,j)\mid i,j\in\{1..10\}\}|}=\frac{40}{100}=4/10 $$
And the probability that both are red is:

$$\frac{|\{(i,j)\mid i,j\in\{1..4\}\}|}{|\{(i,j)\mid i,j\in\{1..10\}\}|}=\frac{16}{100} $$

Comment: i understand but my question why you do p(r).p(r) i know this is a rule but by logic the probability of picking 2 ball red with replacement 4/10 and thank you for your answer

Comment: why we can calculate the probability of 2 or more Independent events by multiplying

Comment: Example: Why is it unlikely to get, say, 7 heads in a row, when each toss of a coin has a ½ chance of being Heads?

Because we are asking two different questions:

Question 1: What is the probability of 7 heads in a row?

Answer: ½×½×½×½×½×½×½ = 0.0078125 (less than 1%).
Question 2: Given that we have just got 6 heads in a row, what is the probability that the next toss is also a head?

Answer: ½, as the previous tosses don't affect the next toss. why we multiplicate

Comment: @ShadyHany I edited my answer to help you with what I think you didn't get. I hope it helps.

Comment: thank thank you i really understand now you are very helpful for me but i have anaother question i know the multiplication rule is true but i want to know how he create it from the beginning